# Can $http.put write data to JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-http

I apologize for the newbie question but I am getting conflicting answers to this while searching on the net.

I have created an AngularJS app to read from a JSON file using $http.get and display the data as a form with each form element binded with ng-model.  Ideally I would like the user to be able to edit the desired field and click save, then have that data updated in the JSON file.  I have been told that to do this you will need a 3rd party server like NodeJS, but I am seeing other examples that show it being done in videos.  Can someone tell me if this is possible without the 3rd party server and if so what is the best practice for doing this.

Thank you

Comment: A server isn't really a third party per se ... what server are you using right now to actually serve the files?

Comment: I am just running it through the WebStorm viewer, we use Apache for our main App.

Comment: Apache with anything else or just as a static file server?

Comment: Are you storing these in actually physical JSON files or are you using some sort of persistence layer (i.e. database) to store the data and then serializing/deserializing JSON for communication? If just physical file, why?  Are you going to be able to handle concurrency?

Comment: You'll need server side processing to save to the JSON file - whether under the hood you're saving directly to the JSON file, to a flat file or database. What server side programming languages do you have? (PHP, .NET, python, Java, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$http GET (for resource located on client) will not work with the Chrome browser and will give a CORS error (unless you disable Chrome web security by opening Chrome using run .../chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files -disable-web-security). Firefox gives an error saying the JSON in not well formed even though it is. Browsers don't seem to like it.

HTML5 LocalStorage is your best bet for client storage where you wish to perform CRUD operations and have the data survive past page refresh. A good example of this is the [TodoMVC example]
(https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/angularjs)

A very simple example that saves a json file to localstorage and reads the contents of localstorage is shown. The Service contains a getter and a setter method to interact with localstorage.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<body ng-app = "app">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form>
<input placeholder="Enter Name.." ng-model="newContact"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"    
       ng-click="addContact(newContact)">Add
    </button>
  </form>
  <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index">
    {{contact.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**APP.JS**

```
angular.module('app', ['app.services'] )
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, html5LocalStorage) {
    //create variable to hold the JSON
var contacts = $scope.contacts = html5LocalStorage.get();
$scope.addContact = function(contact) {     
  $scope.contacts.push( {"name":contact} ); //Add new value
  html5LocalStorage.put($scope.contacts);   //save contacts to local storeage
    }
});
```

**SERVICES.JS**

```
angular.module('app.services', [] )
.factory('html5LocalStorage', function () {
  var STORAGE_ID = 'localStorageWith_nG_KEY';   //the Local storage Key
    return {
    //Get the localstorage value
    get: function () 
    {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_ID) || '[]');
    },
    //Set the localstorage Value
    put: function (values) 
    {
        localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_ID, JSON.stringify(values));
    }
  };
});
```

Otherwise you could use Node and Express and store the JSON file on the server. Use file system module 'fs-extra' to interact with the json file.
You would have to create RESTful API routes for the client to interact with the server using $http and perform CRUD operations.

- /put
- /get
- /delete
- /post

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested to see these videos of this being done without the server writing to the file.  You cant just "post the .json file" and have it replace the old one, unless you configure your server (apache, nginx, tomcat, node) to do so.